# Why and when to use componentDidMount in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was going through the react tutorial and I'm confused as to why componentDidMount is used?

Comment: If an answer helped you out, it's considered good practice that you mark it as an 'Answer', this way you might help other people who have a similar problem in the future (see for more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One really useful way to use `componentDidMount` is for AJAX requests.

So, imagine a situation where you want to get a list of Comments for an Article. After the component is created you may want to go retrieve the list of comments from the server and then display them to the user.

Here's an example (from the React tutorial):
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#updating-state

Answer (score 6):

I think the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) covers it well enough:

> #### Mounting: componentDidMount
>
> ```
> void componentDidMount()
> ```
>
> Invoked once, only on the client (not on the server), immediately after the initial rendering occurs. At this point in the lifecycle, you can access any refs to your children (e.g., to access the underlying DOM representation). The `componentDidMount()` method of child components is invoked before that of parent components.
>
> If you want to integrate with other JavaScript frameworks, set timers using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, or send AJAX requests, perform those operations in this method.

Answer (score 0):

It is called exactly once and when The component has been initialized. The component has bind with the container element and rendered successfully. All the properties and initial states has been initialized. You can now call setState and other component function on this component, manipulate it and so on. Simply it is the starting point for you to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount()` executes after the `render()` at first execution. After that it executes before the `render()` according to React Lifecycle.

`componentDidMount()` , One really useful way to us AJAX requests